# Worksheet change target + sorting

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

im using VBA event Worksheet_Change to update some cell values (after another cell in same row is changed), and also need to sort them before that update. But here i met issue, when i use this

```
 If loadInProgress = False Then


    If target.Column = 10 Or target.Column = 5 Then
        Call datasetLabelChange
        Call calculateModel(target)
    End If
End If
```

datasetLabelChange -> is function which sort working range
calculateModel(target) -> is function which update cell

then sort is okay, but after sort (if target change position) target dont have correct row and column values to perform update of cell. Is there posibility to track target after sort? (update his .row and .column to where it is after sort)

Comment: you mean that your 'Target' value is in another cell after the sorting is done?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.EnableEvents = False` so the routine does not try to run on top of itself.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not CBool(loadInProgress) Then
        On Error GoTo FallThrough
        'next line important so it doesn't try to run on top of itself
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.Column = 10 Or Target.Column = 5 Then
            Call datasetLabelChange
            Call calculateModel(Target)
        End If
    End If
FallThrough:
    'restore event triggers
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for efort, but i need to perform sorting, then update value. As Goosebumbs asked, my problem is that target is refering to another cell after sorting and i need to keep relation

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have sorted this out by now

but for others looking for the same thing the easiest solution is to use
$ sign in your references this way when sort is used the reference remain unchanged

eg =Sheet1!$G$1 will remain unchanged where as =sheet1!G1 will be

also the worksheet change example will fix you issue by calling a routine that updates all your formulas

Martyn